# Using Srand With Enums

Tags: c++, enums, srand

I have an enum of colours:

```
enum colour_t {red, blue, green, yellow, orange, white};
```

and I'm making a Rubik's Cube scrambler, so I need to use srand or some sort of randomizer to select a colour for each square. Is it possible to use srand with enum values or will I have to give it some integer parameters (1-6) and have a case for each number corresponding to a colour.

Thanks, 
Tristan

Comment: Naively, use the modulus operator.  (If you care about super strong randomness, some PRNGs can generate sequences that have patterns under certain moduli, so you should do some research on the PRNG you are using if that is the case). Also, since your modulus probably doesn't evenly divide the range, you may want to discard a handful of extreme values so that you ensure each bin is the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast:

```
static_cast<colour_t>(rand() % (white + 1))
```

Comment: Running this always returns white, maybe I'm implementing it wrong? I implemented it by saying: "colour_t colour = static_cast<colour_t>(rand() % (white + 1));" and then having an if statement to check if (colour == red) blue, green, etc.

Comment: @Tristan You're almost certainly calling `srand()` wrongly... make sure you call it once and only once when your program starts (normally `std::srand(std::time(NULL));` atop `main()` is good enough), then each time you call `rand()` you'll get a pseudo-random result.  If you keep calling `srand()` with the same seed, it'll reset the sequence and start yielding the same series of pseudo-random numbers....